# How do I style a PHP form RESULTS page?

Tags: php, forms

I've gota working form that when you click "submit" it takes you to a results page - all fine.

However, is it possible to add divs etc to make the page look a bit nicer? If so, how? At the moment when i add divs in it just ignores them!

Thanks,
Steph

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styleResults.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<TITLE>Ideo Accounting - Results</TITLE>
</head>
<body>
<H2>Results</H2>

<?
$customers = $_POST['customers'];
$suppliers = $_POST['suppliers'];
$bank = $_POST['bank'];
$creditcard = $_POST['creditcard'];

$totalqty = 0;
$totalamount = 0.00;

define("PRICE", 0.75);

$totalqty = $customers + $suppliers + $bank + $creditcard;
$totalamount = number_format($totalqty*PRICE, 2);

echo "<BR>\n";
echo "Total transactions: $totalqty<br>\n";
echo "Estimated monthly fee: &pound;$totalamount<BR>\n";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put any HTML styling elements in between the `"` double quotes after the `echo` statements, they will definitely not be ignored.

Look into your browser's "view source" page to see whether they get output or not. My guess is the `div`s you output have no CSS styling at all, so you won't see anything.

**Code improvement suggestion:**

It might be easier to work with the HTML if you change its structure a bit. Remove the three `echo` lines, and after the `?>` add

```
<BR>
Total transactions: <?php echo $totalqty;?><br>
Estimated monthly fee: &pound;<?php echo $totalamount;?><BR>
```

the PHP output is then part of your HTML code, and you can place `div`s and other elements as you please without having to take care not to break the PHP string. You can even move  the `<?php=$...?>` snippets around, you just have to be careful that they stay intact.

Comment: I've tried the code improvement suggestion you said but it says:

syntax error, unexpected '=' in line 35 (which is the Total transactions: <?php=$totalqty;?><br> line)
....

Comment: I think it's more like this: <?php echo $totalqty; ?><br>

Comment: @Phill @Steph cheers, good point. I forgot that the `=` notation works with short open tags only. Changed the example.

Comment: <?php= is apparently scheduled for inclusion in PHP 6